# I want to change the look of my donate button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, paypal

On my website I am creating I was to use the bootstrap button btn-primary, as my donate button instead of the one offered by PayPal. My problem is when I attempt to change the button, the button no longer works.

Here is my working piece of code:

```
<div id="donate-button-image">
  <input type="image" 
  src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" 
  border="0" name="submit" onClick="CalculateOrder(this.form)">
</div>
```

When I change the second line input type to button instead of image, and change src to class so I can specify I want btn-primary, the OnClick function just stops working, as seen below

```
<div id="donate-button-image">
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" border="0" 
  name="submit"onClick="CalculateOrder(this.form)">
</div>
```

with the paypal button, I would be taken to the PayPal page to donate, but now after changing it, the button has no function. What I don't get is how am I changing more than just the style of the button? any help is appreciated, thank you!

here is the javascript:

```
function CalculateOrder(form){
 var radG1;
 var totalAmount=0;

for (var i = 0; i < document.myform.os0.length; i++){
 if(document.myform.os0[i].checked==true){
   radG1=document.myform.os0[i].value;}
    }
 if(radG1 == "5.00"){
  document.myform.amount.value = '5.00';
  document.myform.item_number.value = "WF-5-00";
  }
 else if(radG1 == "10.00"){
  document.myform.amount.value = '10.00';
  document.myform.item_number.value = "WF-10-00";
  }
 else if(radG1 == "25.00"){
  document.myform.amount.value = '25.00';
  document.myform.item_number.value = "WF-25-00";
  }
 else if(radG1 == "50.00"){
 document.myform.amount.value = '50.00';
 document.myform.item_number.value = "WF-50-00";
  }

 else if(radG1 == "Other"){
  document.myform.amount.value = '0.00';
  document.myform.item_number.value = "WF-0-00";
  }  
}
```

Comment: can you post this function `CalculateOrder`

Comment: Why is it an input? shouldn't it just be a button?

Comment: 3 radio buttons of fixed amounts and 1 radio button being amount user wants to donate

Comment: i can send that too but literally all I have changed is the input type and the buttons source